# How to add a twitter website box?

Tags: html, twitter, widget

I'm trying to find out how I can add a twitter profile stream to my website. Using some kind of auto generated code I can insert as an HTML snippet (like the facebook page box features that FB provide).

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've had a good Google around and haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Scott

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the first result I found in Google: http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets. Seems to be what you want, tutorials and everything. Also, the very first result for "twitter website box" is a tutorial to archieve exactly what you want.

Comment: Great thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. I can be a Google retard at the best of times. :)

Answer (score -2):

you the box create at this site:  http://www.twitter-fanbox.com/

Sorce: [Tecnologia Geek](http://tecnologiageek.com/)